# Infopath forms added to sharepoint library/list. Then the data that have been submit through "submit button" will save in another list

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer, document-library, infopath, infopath-data-connections

1. How do I publish the InfoPath form in library/list in sharepoint? (Means like once we open the list/ library, we can straight fill up the form)
2. Then when the user fills up the form and presses the "submit button". The data that have been submitting will be stored in another list (2nd picture)

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can configure your **Submit** button to submit data based on a specific **rule** to submit the form to another data connection (`In your case, it's the second lis`t)

- **First,** you need to add the second list as a `Secondary Data Connection`.
- **Second,** In `Data` Tab > Click on `Submit Option` > Check `Perform Custom Action using Rule`

  [image]
- In the `Form Submit` Rule > Click on `Submit Using Data Connection` > and select `Secondary Data Connection`.

  [image]